# Nice Error Messages for "no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'" in ANTLR4

Tags: antlr4

I want to show more beautiful error message to my users.

For example if someone types `integer i=` the error message `no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'` appears. That's totally fine and predictable due to my grammar rules but I'm figuring out ways to improve those messages. If the = is missing in the example above the message changes to `mismatched input '<EOF>' expecting '='`. Again predictable but I can do more stuff on things like this in my code than on a general input error.

Should I catch them in the code and try to evaluate which cases is meant? Or is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you'd create your own error listener and add it to the parser where you can deal with the error yourself. For that remove any existing error listeners (one for the console is automatically registered by default), by calling `parser.removeErrorListeners();`. Define an own error listener class derived from `BaseErrorListener` and add an instance of that to your parser via `parser.addErrorListener(yourListener);`. You can see an example of such a custom error listener in the ANTLR runtime (search for `XPathLexerErrorListener`). Override the `syntaxError` method and use the provided info to generate your own error message. There is already a message passed in to this method (in addition to other stuff like line + char position, exception etc.), which you cannot customize as it comes directly from generated code. So best is probably to leave that alone and start from scratch (the passed in exception is your best option you have).

Comment: That's what I'm doing at this moment. I'm trying to figure out in my own error listener what I could or should display to the user to support him solve the issue. Thanks for the confirmation that I'm on the right track!